# Where can I get logs of servlet in Oracle Apache IAS?

Tags: java, oracle, apache, servlets

I am using  Oracle Apache IAS,In which file Java servlet prints logs of system.out.print(); method ?

My servlet is in `IAS/Apache/Jserv/servlets` directory and I couldn't found 
printed in `IAS/Apache/Jserv/logs/` directory.

Thanks!

Comment: it will display in console or command prompt.

Comment: Well, System.out.println appears on the console when I'm debugging in Eclipse.

Comment: `System.out` is always stdout, therefore it depends on what stdout is. But you shouldn't be using that in a servlet context anyway, you should use a logging API, which Java is in no shortage of...